# Dealing with Enums in Asp MVC Telerik Grid and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums, telerik, telerik-grid

For web application in development(ASP.Net MVC), I'm using the telerik grid. The grid is bound to an IQueryable of my list, because it's a big table, and I want that telerik apply it's filter on the list, and then executes this result, not dowloading 10'000 rows(with the joined tables), and then with the filter, use only rows.

I'm using(and I really need it for this page, it's one of the key feature) the filter/order of the grid.

One of the main column(determining the kind of the data) is an enum.

The problem is that I get a `"Specified type member is not supported in linq to entities"` as soon as I'm trying to filter/sort it.

I've to bind it on the enum(and not the mapped int) because if I use the id, filters/order by will be on an int, and I can't expect that the user knows the id of the foreign table.

I just cannot implement myself again all grids parameter(located in url)(I assume, it's either I do everything, or nothing) and filter it correctly, order it correctly).

Do you have an idea of workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how your Entity Model looks like but I'll suppose that you've something like this Model:

```
public partial class Project
{    
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

and the Status property represents your enum value then you've this enum:

```
public enum ProjectStatuses
{
    Current = 1,
    Started = 2,
    Stopped = 3,
    Finished = 4,
}
```

Then just create new ViewModel like this :

```
public class ProjectDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public ProjectStatuses StatusValue { get { return (ProjectStatuses) Status; } }
        // This property to display in telerik ClientTemplate
        public string StatusName { get { return Enum.GetName(typeof (ProjectStatuses), Status ); } }            
    }
```

And because I love Extension Methods I'll add this one :

```
public static class ModelListExtensions
{
        public static IQueryable<ProjectDetails> ToViewModelDetails(this IQueryable<Project> modelList)
        {
            return modelList.Select(m => new ProjectDetails
                                             {
                                                 Id = m.Id,
                                                 Name = m.Name,
                                                 Status = m.Status,
                                              };
         }
}
```

---

***Update :***

**Here is the Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int total;
        var viewModel = getGridList(out total);
        ViewBag.Total = total;
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //this Action to get ajax pages
    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult ReGetIndex(GridCommand command, int roleId)
    {
        int total;
        var list = getGridList(out total, roleId, command);
        return View(new GridModel {Data = list, Total = total});
    }


    private IEnumerable<ProjectDetails> getGridList(out int total, GridCommand command = null)
    {
        command = command ?? new GridCommand {Page = 1};
    foreach (var descriptor in command.SortDescriptors)
    {
        if (descriptor.Member == "StatusValue")
            descriptor.Member = "Status";

    }
    foreach (FilterDescriptor descriptor in command.FilterDescriptors)
    {
        if (descriptor.Member == "StatusValue")
            descriptor.Member = "Status";
    }

    var list = modelService.AllAsQuery()
            .ToViewModelDetails() // To convert it to our ViewModel if we have one
            .Where(command.FilterDescriptors);

    total = list.Count();

    return (IEnumerable<ProjectDetails>) list.Sort(command.SortDescriptors)
                                                  .Page(command.Page - 1, command.PageSize)
                                                  .GroupBy(command.GroupDescriptors).ToIList();
}
```

**And this is the View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectDetails>
@{
    Html.Telerik()
        .Grid(Model)
        .Name("ProjectsGrid")
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .Select("ReGetIndex", "Projects"))
        .Pageable(page => page.Style(GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown | GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric).Total(ViewBag.Total))
        .Columns(column =>
                     {
                         column.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden(true);
                         column.Bound(m => m.Name);
                         column.Bound(m => m.StatusValue).ClientTemplate("<#= StatusName #>");
                     })
        .Render();
}
```

***Update :***

*If you want to enforce at least one sort order you could use something like this:*

```
 if (!command.SortDescriptors.Any())
 {
     command.SortDescriptors.Add(new SortDescriptor {Member = "YourDefaultProperty"});
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this when binding the grid to a property of my model?

Comment: @J4N if you don't want to add ViewModel class then you could just extend your Model in a partial class and just put the Two others properties "`StatusValue` and `StatusName`" in our example.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you show me actually how you are binding datas to the grid in the view?

Comment: Your solution just seems to be awesome, I will try it in the next few days! If it works, I definitely ows you a beer! I didn't know anything about the GridCommand. If I've Server binding, I suppose that I can put this as parameter of my action and load it like you.

Comment: Your welcome dude ;) BTW if you want to use my way in "Where, Sort, Page and GroupBy" mthods then you should add `using Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions` to your Controller

Comment: I made some tests, I cannot make it works with server binding(which I should have), the main problem is that the GridCommand in my action parameter is always an empty object. Actually I only have a [GridAction] on my action, with the GridCommand parameter into it, and then, pretty much the same method as you. I've no ".DataBinding()" method on the grid view, because I've data in the model that I bind with the "BindTo". I was having that using the BindTo + the .DataBinding() was redundant for a server binding?

Comment: I found the missing point: the GridName was not correctly filled.
I juste have one error, when I'm going on the page 4, I got an exception telling me that the Skip method has to be called before the order by, any idea why?

Comment: Yes actually EF enforce you to add OrderBy before the Take statement so you need to ensure that your grid has at least one OrderBy statement. If you have a problem with it tell me and i'll update my answer. BTW if my answer was good for you please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Done, I don't want that you miss the bounty. I will create a class, which is able to handle in a generic manner enums. I still have to find how to ORDER by the enum text and not the enum position, I got some ideas, but it implies the usage of indexof, which is not supported by EF. Thank you for all your help

Comment: Thanks :) And about OrderBy Enum text i think the only way you can get it is by ordering the enum itself and in your case i guess that you're using Globalization and that's make it so difficult So please if you configured how to do it tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have choice (or few annoying choices)

Wether you use a class instead of enum (but if you used an enum, that's because it was better).

Or you "pseudo-sort" your enum, and use the mapped int.

```
public enum TT
    {
        Brown = 0,
        Green = 1
    }
```

Of course, you'll have to check the actual datas (mapped int) in your DB and update them to conform to the new order (can't change enum order without impact). And you'll have to do that everytime you want to insert a value between existing enum values.

Or you wait for next EF / linq / c# version, which should have enum support in linq2entities

Comment: I just can't, the website is localized, so sometimes it will be the Brown which comes first, some times it will be the Green one. And I can't put a class here, the database design has been locked several month ago for API/backup/... needs.(and like you said, this was really the best choice for the DB. I understand happen, but it should be a workaround.